# Postfix - excluding recipient from wildcard

Tags: postfix, wildcard

I'm currently attempting to receive and deliver all emails to `*@example.com` to `me@example.com`. However I'd also like to reject all mail to `bad@mydomain.com`. I essentially need a wildcard where I can define one (or more) exceptions to the wildcard.

I've currently configured my wildcard via a `virtual_alias_maps = hash:/etc/postfix/virtual` directive which works with the following configuration:

```
@example.com me
me@example.com  me
```

I'd now like to reject all email going to `bad@example.com`, rather than delivering it to my or any other mailbox. I can't seem to find information on how to reject based on specific addresses in a wildcard.

**How do I stop emails from being accepted due to matching the wildcard in the virtual_alias_maps?**

Comment: I think there exists a special target to explicitly return a failure for a lookup. You could achieve rejecting mails to bad@example.com with a line like “bad@examble.com FAIL”. Unfortunately, I can’t find this anymore in Postfix’s online documentation.

Answer (score 2):

`virtual` appears to just be mappings; to block sending to a particular email I'd probably try an `access(5)` entry tied to the recipient checks:

```
smtpd_recipient_restrictions =
  ...
  check_recipient_access hash:/etc/postfix/rctpaccess
  ...
```

And then something like:

```
cd /etc/postfix
echo "bad@example.com REJECT" >> rctpaccess
postmap rctpaccess
```